# Having trouble joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up a table for invoice_line_items which links to an inventory table which needs to be joined to various tables for extra fields depending on the type of inventory.

```
invoice_line_items < inventory_id> JOIN inventory < type = m> JOIN inv_extra_m / < type = d> JOIN inv_extra_d

SELECT DISTINCT l.invoice_line_number
FROM invoice_line_items l
LEFT JOIN inventory i
ON i.inventory_id = l.inventory_id
JOIN (
SELECT i.*
FROM inventory i
JOIN inv_extra_m m ON i.inventory_id = m.inventory_id 
WHERE (i.type = 'a' OR i.type = 'b'))
UNION
SELECT i.*
FROM inventory i
JOIN inv_extra_d d ON i.inventory_id = d.inventory_id 
WHERE i.type = 'd'
) ie ON ie.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
WHERE l.invoice_id = 1
```

Comment: explain better  .. you have errors? .. wrong result?   . what mean " why I can't tag mysql-query"   ... .. what's the question?

Comment: Idk if I tagged the right tags. I tried to tag it as mysql-query but it won't accept it. Anyway my error is:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id ) ie ON ie.inventory_id = i.inventory_id WHERE l.invoice_id = 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 14

Comment: There is no limit clause in your query?

Comment: Would you like to provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: the code you provided is not related  to the error message in you comment ..

Comment: I've played it with more since I posted and I somehow managed to figure out what's wrong. I'll edit with the correct format.

I have another question though. How do I union rows with different column count? Can I pad the shorter row with more null columns? Or is selecting them separately and merging them on the app layer a better solution? (Invoice line items are pulled from tables with different number of columns)

Comment: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You have a improper union sintax  assigni a table name after   each select part

```
    SELECT DISTINCT l.invoice_line_number
    FROM invoice_line_items l
    LEFT JOIN inventory i
    ON i.inventory_id = l.inventory_id
    JOIN (
      SELECT i.*
      FROM inventory i
      JOIN inv_extra_m m ON i.inventory_id = m.inventory_id 
      WHERE (i.type = 'a' OR i.type = 'b')
      UNION
      SELECT i.*
      FROM inventory i
      JOIN inv_extra_d d ON i.inventory_id = d.inventory_id 
      WHERE i.type = 'd' 
      ) ie ON ie.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
    WHERE l.invoice_id = 1
```